# How to create random honeypot credit card data

Tags: credit-card, data-generation, honeypot

So I'd like to create some honeypot credit card data.

Creating the credit card numbers is easy (maybe).  I can just create numeric integer values in a certain range.  If I'm ambitious, I might try to create Luhn valid numbers, though I probably don't want to go that far.  In fact, I'd kind of prefer to create known invalid numbers, which would be a useful technique.  Anyway, as a bare minimum I'll just create some random integers.

Sec code can just be random.  Expiration dates can be within certain ranges, random.

The hard part is:  How can I create random names?  I can't really use existing names, for obvious privacy reasons, even if I were randomly recombining first and last names (John Smith, Jane Doe, Bob Jenkins => John Jenkins, Bob Doe, Jane Jenkins) unless perhaps they're especially generic, I probably won't mind if I create some John Smith names in the random data.

But what can I use to seed the data that is non-harmful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [Fake Name Generator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-random-us-us.php)? They have an [API](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/api.php), and it will generate your CC info as well.

Comment: Awesome.  Looks like there's actually a bulk request form too http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php , which I can definitely use.

Answer (score 0):

Try with some well-known cartoon characters or Append some numbers to names like John1 Doe1 , to avoid privacy issues.

Comment: I don't want to make it obvious, it won't be an especially effective honeypot that way.